# How can I stop mypy complaining when comparing a pd.Series to single value?

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

I have the following code:

```
result = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)]) > pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

However mypy complains with the following:

`error: Unsupported operand types for > ("Series[Any]" and "Timedelta")`

I also tried:

```
s: pd.Series[pd.Timedelta] = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)])
result = s > pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

But that also gives an error:

`error: Unsupported operand types for > ("Series[Timedelta]" and "Timedelta")`

Note that mypy doesn't complain if I just have a series with `int`s such as `pd.Series([10]) > 3`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas-stubs` 1.4.3.220724 does not allow `Timedelta` in `pandas.Series.__gt__`.

This has been fixed in `pandas-stubs` 1.4.3.220801.

## Workarounds for earlier versions

### 1. Exclude that line from type checking

```py
s = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)])
result = s > pd.Timedelta(hours=1)  # type: ignore
```

### 2. Use the flexible wrapper of that comparison operator

In this case, [`pandas.Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html).

```py
s = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)])
result = s.gt(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```

### 3. Explicitly declare to type checkers that it's actually supported

```py
from typing import cast

import pandas as pd


class SupportsGtTimedelta:
    def __gt__(self, other: pd.Timedelta): ...


s = cast(SupportsGtTimedelta, pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)]))
result = s > pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your pandas or python version is outdated u can install the latest version and then try u can take a reference of my screenshot for version of python and pandas  of 3.10.5, 1.4.3
[image]
if further, u faced a problem comment to me with a screenshot